# Issues using sublime text to edit command line in VI mode

Tags: zsh, vi-mode

I am using the following to edit the current command line in Sublime Text 2 (using a working `subl` alias)

**`.zshrc`**

```
set -o vi

EDITOR='subl'; export EDITOR

bindkey -M vicmd v edit-command-line
```

This opens up sublime, but the window is blank. If I set the editor back to Vim, I am able to open a new vim buffer with the current command line in it. `fc` works just fine.

Comment: Don't know what sublime is, but note that `$EDITOR` is meant to contain the path to an editor or more exactly an editor command, something that you can `execp` (to be used by anything needing to start an editor, not only `fc`) not a shell alias.

Comment: `EDITOR` should be `subl -w`, not sure if that will help... And BTW, there's a sublimetext2 tag over at StackOverflow that might be of use next time you have a question - I know more users/plugin programmers monitor it there

Comment: @MattDMo ``subl -w`` seems to have sorted it. Thanks Matt. If you want to post that as an answer I will accept it : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [the OSX docs](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html) the `EDITOR` environment variable should be set to `subl -w`, which means "Wait for the files to be closed before returning." This behavior is undocumented but similar in Linux, where `subl` is generally a symlink to the `sublime_text` executable file, wherever you decide to install it.